# Maven Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, dependency-injection

I have a problem with resolving my maven dependencies or at least i think so. I looked for similiar problems but i couldn't get an answer that could help me.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyUtils.isScopedTarget(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerMethodProcessor.afterSingletonsInstantiated(EventListenerMethodProcessor.java:89)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

that's the exception i get.

here is my spring-servlet-xml

```
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sss.*">
</context:component-scan>
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view."></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" >
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}">
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sssssssssssssssssssssssss</groupId>
  <artifactId>sssssssssssssssssssssssss</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
       <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                 <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>
       <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.3</version>
       <configuration>
       <source>1.8</source>
       <target>1.8</target>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  </project>
```

here is my dao class:

```
@Repository
public class StockDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public boolean addStock(Stock entity){
    try{
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();return false;}
    }

   public List<Stock> findAll(){
    return       (List<Stock>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Stock.class);
}
```

i used maven clean on my project and now i got a new exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock"/> in the configuration:
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to load class declared as <mapping class="com.sss.model.Stock"/> in the configuration:
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:650)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1047)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1477)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1023)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:588)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sss.model.Stock
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:123)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.parseMappingElement(AnnotationConfiguration.java:647)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1589)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1568)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1047)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1477)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1023)
org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:588)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:189)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:633)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:681)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: I think your servlet-api.jar is not being loaded. Check if you have such a dependency, if not, add it.

Comment: Spring 4 supports servlet-api.jar 3.1 could you try upgrading your servlet-api.jar. Also make sure thats packaged into you lib folder of the application.

Comment: You are mixing different spring versions. You have version 4.2.0 for web and JDBC, however the spring data dependency is pulling in older, 4.1 or 4.0 versions. Next to that you have a `spring-orm` 1.0.2 dependency not sure what that is but it looks really old...

Comment: so what version should i use where ?

Answer (score 7):

Add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` deployment descriptor file into `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the version of `org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedProxyUtils` that you are running against is different to the version you are compiling against.

Looking at the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/scope/ScopedProxyUtils.html#isScopedTarget-java.lang.String-) it says that isScopedTarget was introduced in version 4.1.4.

I'd check the jars in tomcat's lib and in your war (or maybe the exploded war directory). Perhaps you have two different version of the spring aop jars?

How do you deploy to tomcat? Do you do a clean deploy (ie delete the old deployment first) or a dirty deploy (ie on top of an old deployment without deleting forst). I'm guessing you're doing a dirty deploy which is causing the issue.

Comment: i do a dirty deployement. a clean one means run as -> maven clean first ?

Comment: thank you. the clean seems to have my problem solved somehow. Did this  changed the version to some usable ones ?

Comment: I'm guessing that sometime in the past you were using an older version of the spring aop jars. Looks like you've changed to a newer version but didn't cleanup the old war. My guess is that you had two versions of the jars on the classpath. Cleaning the war directory removed the old jars from the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add dependency for spring aop

I was facing the same exception I added following dependency and it worked for me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>your spring framework version</version>
</dependency>
```

Check whether this works for you or not

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first spring-aop dependency
* if you dont have a spring-aop you have to add
* if you have a spring-aop dependecy most probably older version comes from different spring project.

You have to check with dependecy:tree or development ide your project maven dependencies.

Best Regards